# What is the simplest mathematical concept that does not map to a physical phenomenon?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, applications

One of my colleagues argues that everything in math proves something in the physical world. For instance, he claims that the existence of math to describe fractals proves the infinite divisibility of matter (which is a non sequitur conclusion to make).

What is some simple mathematical concept that absolutely does not map to the physical world, contrary to this belief?

Comment: I think we are _in_ the physical world, so, at worst, anything made up by people (e.g., artificial mathematics, as opposed to natural), is still _in_ the world, so is _already_ mapped to the world as much as any human conception. A more penetrating question would be about whether a given mathematical (or other human...) idea _clarifies_ (still, to human perception) anything about the world, perhaps other than itself, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I like this style of philosophical arguing.  Semantic (as in vocabulary) arguments are only interesting when the arguers realize that it is a semantic argument and know how to make a valid semantic argument.  Anyway, since it occurred to me, maybe negative integers?  How can you have a negative amount of something?

Comment: IMO math does not prove anything in the physical world, suppose one knows all the math, but knows nothing about the physical world, he cannot *prove* anything about the physical world. What happens is that we observe some physical phenomena or properties can be modeled using mathematical concepts. Without observing the world we cannot chose what part of math to use.

Comment: Possible counterargument: If we assume a world in which matter is _not_ infinitely divisible (and whether or not our world has that property, it is certainly something that can be imagined), would anything necessarily prevent the inhabitants of that world from _thinking up_ mathematics that describe fractals?

Comment: Protons and electrons? The conservation of energy? @DanielIV

Comment: @Luis As I said it is a semantic argument, but one could just say that you can only have a positive number of proton and a positive number of electrons, and even if you assume energy is discrete, one could say that it only exists in positive amounts and that any negative amount is simply our interpretation.  I'm not saying this is the only way to view it, but it is a way.

Comment: @DanielIV I realised it probably sounded like I was challenging your opinion. I was not, rather asking what you think of those. You are right,there are too many ways to view it, and if something is correct is ill-defined. Sorry if it sounded as I was challenging your opinion.

Comment: So for example in the case of fractals one should first show (or assume for some practical reason) that something is infinitely divisible and then model it by fractals, fractals does not prove divisiblity. One can look it like that, discrete math proves everything is discrete while continuous math proves every thing is continuous!

Comment: IMO math just helps us to find logical implications of the mathematical model we chose

Comment: When our theories about the world fail, the math related to them is not refuted, if just the math proved the theory, then math must get refuted when the theory fail.

Comment: With tongue in cheek: Any number $>10^{80}$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: But that would leave out googol (which is what 'Google' is based on), and googolplex, and Graham's number, and, for that matter, the number of arrangements of chess pieces on the chess board (which, I'm given to understand is about 10^112).

Comment: BTW, the converse of the notion that every mathematical result, no matter how abstruse, is reflected in the real world somehow, is Catherine Attard’s thesis, that one should have the capability to understand life experiences from a mathematical perspective. https://eric.ed.gov/?id=EJ978128

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No one knows the true nature of the physical world. However, recent work seems to suggest that it is quite discrete. That is, things like real numbers may not represent anything real. Also, it seems likely that the entire observable universe can exist in only finitely many possible states. If this is so, then likely nothing infinite in mathematics represents reality.

If you don't want to go to such extremes, I think you will still find it extremely difficult to find anything in the real world relating to even fairly small ordinal numbers, like $\omega_1$, or even fairly small cardinal numbers like $\aleph_2$.

Comment: Very good points about highly infinite things... and, yet, I seriously suspect that human perceptions about various "infinities" do admit finitistic interpretations. E.g., AxCh as an over-the-top umbrella justification for finite choice schemes. To my mind, the point/issue is about human interpretation... e.g., we are in the "finite" world, and pretend to conceive of hugely infinite things... how is _this_ already possible? :)

Answer (score 1):

Points and lines are not physical objects because a point has zero volume and a line has zero thickness.